# PHP- Textbox array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, textbox

i have a form which allow users to add dynamic field. I have name the textbox into an array eg. msgreceipient[] and enquiry[].

I want to get the value of each array for both msgrecipient and enquiry to insert into the database.

So msgreceipient and enquiry is required for the SQL insert statement.

I need extract msgrecipient[0] and enquiry[0], then insert into the database, after that followed by [1],[2], etc depend on how many fields are there.

This is my code but it seems wrong.

```
$msgrecipient = $_POST['msgrecipient'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];

if($result)
{
    $recipient ="";
    $enqirydata ="";

    foreach($msgrecipient as $value)
    {
        $recipient = $value;
        foreach($enquiry as $value2)
        {
            $enquirydata = $value2;
        }
        $query = "INSERT into database"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you want.

```
$msgrecipient = $_POST['msgrecipient'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];

if( $result ){
    foreach( $msgrecipient as $index => $msgdata ){
        $enqdata=$enquiry[ $index ];
        $sql='insert into `table` set `recipient`="'.$msgdata.'", `enquriy`="'.$enqdata.'";';
        $db->query( $sql );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($msgrecipient); $i++)
    {
        $recipient = $msgrecipient[$i];
        $enquirydata = $enquiry[$i];
        $query = "INSERT into database";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so simple,
just loop your `$_POST['msgrecipient'];` using foreach loop or for loop